# Sort Delphi TStringList by frequency

Tags: delphi

I have a TStringList of csv values; at the moment each string has four values, v0, v1, v2, v3, any of which may be duplicated.  I want to add a 5th value (v4) to each string which will be the count of v3.  The list should then be sorted in descending order by v4, v3.

for example, this data:
1, 2, 3, 4
1, 3, 4, 4
2, 2, 1, 2
1, 2, 3, 4
3, 1, 2, 2
3, 1, 2, 1

should return the following list:
1, 2, 3, 4, 3
1, 3, 4, 4, 3
1, 2, 3, 4, 3
2, 2, 1, 2, 2
3, 1, 2, 2, 2
3, 1, 2, 1, 1
where the 5th element in each line is the frequency of the 4th element, and it is sorted in descending order by that element.

This is NOT a homework question,

I am currently saving the list to Excel using COM, so have a sheet containing 4 columns.  I then insert a formula into column 5 =COUNTIF(D:D, D1), which counts the occurrences of v4.  I then sort the sheet by column 5 descending and re-import the sheet back into a stringlist.  This works, but I am aware that not all my users will have Excel, so I was hoping for an easier solution.

Comment: You should know by now, that homework questions, although perfectly OK to ask here, should be clearly announced as such. The reason being, so anyone answering knows to formulate the answer to help you learn. You should also know that you are required to show your own attempt to solve the problem. So, please edit your question to include your own code, indicate what doesn't work as it should and be sure to ask only one detailed question.

Comment: Edited the question to show my current attempts to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach might look like this:

```pascal
uses
  Classes,
  StrUtils;

function SortValues(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
var
  Left, Right: TStringDynArray;
begin
  Left := SplitString(List[Index1], ',');
  Right := SplitString(List[Index2], ',');
  Result := Right[4] - Left[4];
  if Result = 0 then
    Result := Right[3] - Left[3];  
end;

var
  CSV: TStringList;
  I, J, Frequency: Integer;
  Values, Value2: TStringDynArray;
begin
  CSV := TStringList.Create;
  try
    // populate CSV as needed...

    for I := 0 to CSV.Count-1 do
    begin
      Values := SplitString(CSV[I], ',');
      if Length(Values) <> 4 then
        raise Exception.Create('Bad Input!');

      Frequency := 1;
      for J := 0 to CSV.Count-1 do
      begin
        if J <> I then
        begin
          Values2 := SplitString(CSV[J], ',');
          if Length(Values2) <> 4 then
            raise Exception.Create('Bad Input!');
          if Values2[3] = Values[3] then
            Inc(Frequency);
        end;
      end;

      CSV[I] := CSV[I] + ', ' + IntToStr(Frequency);
    end;

    CSV.CustomSort(@SortValues);

    // use CSV as needed...

  finally
    CSV.Free;
  end;
end;
```

However, this has a lot of overhead parsing and re-parsing the CSV strings over and over.  This can be better optimized by reducing how many times the CSV strings are parsed and caching the results, eg:

```pascal
uses
  Classes,
  StrUtils;

type
  PCSVInfo = ^CSVInfo;
  CSVInfo = record
    Line: string;
    Value: Integer;
    Frequency: Integer;
  end;

function SortValues(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
var
  Left, Right: PCSVInfo;
begin
  Left := PCSVInfo(List.Objects[Index1]);
  Right := PCSVInfo(List.Objects[Index2]);
  Result := Right.Frequency - Left.Frequency;
  if Result = 0 then
    Result := Right.Value - Left.Value;
end;

var
  CSV: TStringList;
  I, J: Integer;
  Values: TStringDynArray;
  Info: CSVInfo;
  InfoArr: array of CSVInfo;
begin
  CSV := TStringList.Create;
  try
    // populate CSV as needed...

    SetLength(InfoArr, CSV.Count);

    for I := 0 to CSV.Count-1 do
    begin
      Values := SplitString(CSV[I], ',');
      if Length(Values) <> 4 then
        raise Exception.Create('Bad Input!');
      InfoArr[I].Line := CSV[I];
      InfoArr[I].Value := Values[3];
      InfoArr[I].Frequency := 0;
    end;

    for I := 0 to CSV.Count-1 do
    begin
      InfoArr[I].Frequency := 1;
      for J := 0 to CSV.Count-1 do
      begin
        if (J <> I) and (InfoArr[J].Value = InfoArr[I].Value) then
          Inc(InfoArr[I].Frequency);
      end;
      CSV[I] := CSV[I] + ', ' + IntToStr(InfoArr[I].Frequency);
      CSV.Objects[I] := TObject(@InfoArr[I]);
    end;

    CSV.CustomSort(@SortValues);

    // use CSV as needed...

  finally
    CSV.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively, you can count the frequencies and store them in a `TDictionary` while you are parsing the CSV strings, and then use a `TList<T>` to sort the details, eg:

```pascal
uses
  System.Classes,
  System.Generics.Defaults,
  System.Generics.Collections,
  System.StrUtils;

type
  CSVInfo = record
    Line: string;
    Value: Integer;
    Frequency: Integer;
  end;

var
  CSV: TStringList;
  I, Frequency: Integer;
  Values: TStringDynArray;
  Info: CSVInfo;
  InfoList: TList<CSVInfo>;
  Frequencies: TDictionary<Integer, Integer>;
begin
  CSV := TStringList.Create;
  try
    // populate CSV as needed...

    InfoList := TList<CSVInfo>.Create;
    try
      InfoList.Count := CSV.Count;

      Frequencies := TDictionary<Integer, Integer>.Create;
      try
        for I := 0 to CSV.Count-1 do
        begin
          Values := SplitString(CSV[I], ',');
          if Length(Values) <> 4 then
            raise Exception.Create('Bad Input!');

          Info.Line := CSV[I];
          Info.Value := Values[3];
          Info.Frequency := 0;
          InfoList[I] := Info;

          if Frequencies.TryGetValue(Info.Value, Frequency) then
            Inc(Frequency)
          else
            Frequency := 1;
          Frequencies.AddOrSetValue(Info.Value, Frequency);
        end;

        for I := 0 to InfoList.Count-1 do
        begin
          Info := InfoList[I];
          Info.Frequency := Frequencies[Info.Value];
          InfoList[I] := Info;
        end;
      finally
        Frequencies.Free;
      end;

      InfoList.Sort(
        TDelegatedComparer<CSVInfo>.Create(
          function(const Left, Right: CSVInfo): Integer
          begin
            Result := Right.Frequency - Left.Frequency;
            if Result = 0 then
              Result := Right.Value - Left.Value;
          end
        )
      );

      for I := 0 to InfoList.Count-1 do
      begin
        Info := InfoList[I];
        CSV[I] := Info.Line + ', ' + IntToStr(Info.Frequency);
      end;
    finally
      List.Free;
    end;

    // use CSV as needed...

  finally
    CSV.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @NiMuSi: Also make sure you understand how it works.